# Can I use RHEL packages on CentOS?

Tags: centos, rhel6

Can I use rhel packages on centos? Specifially I am concerned about this repository: http://yum.pgrpms.org/9.1/redhat/rhel-6.3-x86_64/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CentOS is basically recompiled RHEL packages and you can easily install RHEL package on CentOS host. The version number and architecture have to match, of course.

BTW, for postgres we use packages from http://yum.postgresql.org/  on Scientific Linux (yet another RHEL clone).

Comment: thank you for that tip about http://yum.postgresql.org/.

Comment: have you tested your theory? because when a package is compiled targeting another operating system, configuration settings might change.  do you have something to back your statement up?